# Python - Not able to plot graph from a numpy array

Tags: python

I am trying plot a graph with a numpy array but the error occur in `plt.plot(s,s)`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def npArrDefine():
    np.array=[]
    s=np.array
    for i in range(10):
        s.append(i+3)
    plt.plot(s,s)
    plt.axis([0,5,0,20])
    plt.show()
npArrDefine()
```

Comment: Maybe because you're doing this weird thing that you shouldn't `s=np.array`

Comment: Please edit in the full traceback for the error.

Comment: You are providing an alias to the `np.array` constructor and somehow expecting that it has an `append` method.  That makes no sense.  This also makes no sense: `np.array = []`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of things wrong with your code.

1. `np.array=[]` and `s=np.array`. Here, you are setting a name that numpy uses to be an empty list (horrible!), and then you are setting s to be that empty list. Don't do this. Simply do `s=[]`.
2. Later on you are trying to plot by using `plt.plot(s,s)` which means you want to plot `s` against itself. This will always give you a straight 45 degree line with 0 intercept even if your code worked.

Your code block should be:

```
s=[]
for i in range(10):
    s.append(i+3)
s = np.array(s) #This line is optional, pyplot can use any array-like.
plt.plot(s)
...
```